# PyQt: Get the highlighted index from QComboBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to obtain the index of the highlighted item in the QComboBox. How can I access to this variable?

The sample code I have:

```
    ...
    self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.combobox.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    self.combobox.highlighted.connect(self.return_higlighted_index)
    ...

def return_highlighted_index(self):
    print('The current highlighted index is: ', '?')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.combobox.highlighted.connect(self.return_higlighted_index)
```

try something like this (not tested)

```
self.combobox.activated[str].connect(self.return_higlighted_index)

def return_highlighted_index(self, combobox_entry):
    idx = self.combobox.findText(combobox_enty)
    print('The current highlighted index is: {}'.format(idx))
```

So you connect your method `return_highlighted_index` to the combobox whenever it is changed it passes its current highlighted string to the method `return_highlighted_index` as `combobox_entry` with `return_highlighted_index()` you should be able to obtain the index.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the code should be modified as follows

```
    ...
    self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.combobox.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    self.combobox.highlighted[int].connect(self.return_higlighted_index)
    ...

def return_highlighted_index(self, param):
    print('The current highlighted index is: ', param)
```